# how to do minor upgrade of postgresql from 9.0.5 to 9.0.19

Tags: postgresql

Currently I am running 9.0.5 postgresql on production. I found 9.0.19 has fixed many security fixes and would like to upgrade to 9.0.19 (minor).

I tried downloading 9.0.19 from [enterprisedb site](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) but when installing its not detecting the existing version and giving me an upgrade option.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade between minor revision should be a matter of just starting the DB cluster with the new binaries.

Lest assume version 9.0.5 is installed on /opt/postgres/9.0.5 and that you would start the database with:

```
/opt/postgres/9.0.5/bin/pg_ctl start-D /directory/of/database
```

then now you would download the new version of postgres, install it into /opt/postgres/9.0.19 and simply stop and start the db with he new postgres version.

```
/opt/postgres/9.0.19/bin/pg_ctl stop -D /directory/of/database -m fast
/opt/postgres/9.0.19/bin/pg_ctl start -D /directory/of/database
```

Comment: cannot I stop the existing DB and install 9.0.19 on the same directory (9.0.5) ? so that old version of binaries will be replaced by newer/updated version?

Comment: you can, but if something goes wrong you dont have a way to rollback.